# Do computer monitors emit electromagnetic radiation that can damage your face?

Tags: computers, radiation, bioelectromagnetics

*Disclaimer: I am layman in the field, but I have a legit question to ask, so before closing, please note that I am showing enough "pre-research" and ask clarified question.*

---

I used an LCD monitor in the past and now an LED. As more as I have been sitting in front of monitor, my face becomes hotter and drier ( really feel it and after i get away, the "heating" feeling goes away in 1-2 hours), and every day I see the deterioration in my face skin as years go.

I have two questions:

1. Can someone get any harmful level of electromagnetic (or whatever measurement) radiation from monitor, if s/he sits in front of monitor (say, 17 inch) 8 hours a day, 365 days in year. (Some resources I've found are [here](https://emfacademy.com/computer-monitor-radiation-everything-you-need-to-know/), and the demonstration of it like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Squ8r7FFjk) or [this](https://youtu.be/N6VUOUd5XY4?t=34) )?
2. If the above answer is NO, then this 2nd question becomes pointless. But if answer is YES, then What measures can one take to protect himself/herself? I am not asking for a *specific* product recommendation - in general, what kind of  "shields" (i.e. i've found something like  [this](https://youtu.be/N6VUOUd5XY4?t=34)) can be used to get some level of protection?

---

EDIT:

I understand that in all external sources, we might find some products on sale ( neither my links or I am affiliated to any of them. I just found those sources and don't mind if they sell something or not. My topic has emphasized question, and i've included some sources I could find). To say frankly, I am not against to pay money in order to get health/protection. I am quite thanksfull to all sites that talk about problems (even so, if they sell stuff. That is quite normal event, including StackExchange, all business in the world has it's own financial interest. Even asking this question makes some monetary benefit to SE, probably you knew that.) So, instead, I need answers to the subject, however thanks for warning me about possible fraud. But this subject is life-critical to me and I really need all information about the subject.

Comment: Be careful with sites like the one you link to - they state no scientific credentials and often have a financial interest in you buying *protective* equipment. I see that site does indeed have a link to recommended products. Remember, visible light is electromagnetic radiation. Certain frequencies of it (ionising radiation, like x-rays) can be harmful, but we also exposed to these from radioactive decay in the earth and rays from the sun - the author of the site you link to doesn’t seem to address these.

Comment: A web site proclaiming the dangers of EMR that sells unproven stuff to protect you from EMR. What a surprise. I've been sitting in front of monitors almost every day of my life since 1980. My skin is fine. So is the skin of my coworkers. If you have skin problems, I recommend consulting a dermatologist. I also recommend a more critical view of web sites that sell stuff.

Comment: @Chris i've edited question, addressing your mentioned subject.

Comment: @CareyGregory don't be surprised. If you have been sitting in front of pc and has experienced that you havent been harmed, don't neglect all the rest mankind of not being experienced with same. at first, of course, thanks for sharing your experience, but would be a bit nicer to have a more constructive backing of "it's not harmful" opinion. How many of coworkers you have with similar experience? 2,5 or 50 ? have all of them well passed with problem easily and have all of them been unaffected surely?
please, share your experience in more details, it will help the topic a bit i think.

Comment: No, discussing personal medical anecdotes isn't helpful or welcome here. Please read the [help] to get a better idea what this site is about. You should also search this site for things like EMF and EMR. There have been many questions on this subject over the years, and I have yet to see a single, credible piece of evidence that EMR from electronic devices harms anyone.

Comment: Heavens. When you go outside stand under a tree for shade, but don’t stand under a tree or around a tree during a thunderstorm.  If you are low in vitamin D, you don’t need to stand under a tree and you can run around naked for 20 minutes unless you have a history of skin cancer.

Comment: By all means once a day you should get away from all computers, and either stand under a tree or run around in the sun, as advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important thing is to distinguish between CRT monitors and other more modern technologies.

CRT monitors do emit detectable amounts of X-rays and have an extremely strong EM field as a necessary part of their operation. They also have a "degauss" pulse on power-on which is very strong and can damage magnetic media nearby. One of those pages on EM radiation linked to a rat study that was using CRT monitors extremely close to rat cages.

LCD/LED monitors do not have a "standing" field as part of their operation, but leak a small amount of EM from high-frequency signals. I do not believe there is any reliably documented harm from this level of EM.

Comment: thanks for answering, and at least, being an adequate and not attacking (like others) the question, and instead, giving an answer to a layman question I posted. Even though it doesn't fully satisfies my interest and gives complete answer, this is the only answer in this topic. thanks.

Comment: There is a lot of pseudoscience out there trying to convince people that small levels of EM is dangerous, mostly so they can sell you things. Frustration with that is probably why this question got closed so rapidly.

Comment: You're describing very old CRTs, not ones made in recent years, so it would have been good to make that distinction. But mainly your question lacks supporting references, which are required here. Can you fix that, please?

Comment: I still feel this answer and its question consist mainly of a technical part and should be migrated to a technical SE site instead. The specific question left: "Is radiation X (see reference X, X, X) harmful for human health?". Then the question can be solely answered from a medical perspective with proper medical references.

Comment: @BobOrtiz I've tried to update question exactly to express what you say, because I am interested really on that matter, and not specifics in the background of the technology. i just matter health-matters.

Comment: @pjc50, yes, i think that is frustration, if (as you say `... trying to convince people that small levels of EM is dangerous...`) but what I've been trying to explain, is that "small level" is relative, and if that multiplied to 8 hours day X 365 days in a year, might then be "not a small level" ? i dont know, i am layman in this field, and I've just asked.... thanks! i appreciate you answered to my questions in both topics however you could..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly many of the radiations that screens produce are massively reduced from a decade ago. The greatest radiation is infra red in the form of heat, this can dry your skin but no more than being in an office that has heating in anyway or watching tv. 
https://www.radiationanswers.org/radiation-blog/is-that-a-laptop-on-your-lap.html

Comment: thanks for taking time for answer! good answer.